# EllipticPi argument is complex and can not be plotted. How to handle this problem?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

```
inttau[r_]=-(1/Sqrt[0.0345106153943703 - ((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + r) (62.8822 + 
 r))/(3000 r)])
```

> This is my function of r, now I integrated it w r t r

```
tauanalytical[r_] = Integrate[inttau[r], r]
```

> This is what I got after integration, I got this result.

```
-((2.3094 Sqrt[1. + 62.1447/r] (-31.0723 + r) EllipticPi[3.,ArcSin[0.57735 Sqrt[1. + 62.1447/r]], 1.])/Sqrt[-0.965489 + 20./r + 0.000333333 r^2])
```

> later I tried to find the numerical value of;

```
tauanalytical[30] // N
```

> I got this, no the exact number , which I was expecting

```
-126.491 EllipticPi[3., -1.5708 + 0.153761 I, 1.]
```

> Here the second argument of Ellepticpi comes out to be imaginary , it should be real . Please provide necessary assistance.

Comment: Why do you think it should be real?

Comment: MMA version 12.1  For `tauanalytical[30] // N`  I get  -91.3533 - 72.7262 I`

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

inttau[r_] = -(1/
     Sqrt[0.0345106153943703 - ((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + r) (62.8822 + 
            r))/(3000 r)]);

tauanalytical[r_] = Integrate[inttau[r], r];

tauanalytical /@ Range[5, 30, 5]

(* {-1.80511 + 99.3459 I, -5.63104 + 99.3459 I, -11.7122 + 99.3459 I, -21.3022 + 
  99.3459 I, -38.3228 + 99.3459 I, -91.3533 + 99.3459 I} *)
```

Note that the imaginary part is constant. Since you are using an indefinite integral (antiderivative) the result includes an arbitrary (complex) constant.

```
ReImPlot[tauanalytical[r], {r, 0, 30},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .7}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use exact numbers to the extent possible.

```
inttau[r_] = -(1/
       Sqrt[0.0345106153943703 - ((37.3042 - r) (-25.578 + r) (62.8822 + 
              r))/(3000 r)]) // Rationalize[#, 0] & // ExpandAll // Simplify

(* -(1/Sqrt[-(7721175797271411311/7997151075000000000) + 250000455360453/(
  12500000000000 r) + r^2/3000]) *)

tauanalytical[r_] = (Integrate[inttau[r], r] // RootReduce);
```

This antiderivative is real in the range of interest.

```
tauanalytical[30.]

(* -91.3533 *)

Plot[tauanalytical[r], {r, 0, 30}]
```

[image]